# Splitting train/test sets R

Tags: r, split, dataset, glm, sample

In my data set, there's a column with NPS data where numbers change from 0 to 10. 10 and 9 are known as "Promoters", 8 and 7 are known as "Passives" and 6-0 known as "Detractors". I'm planning to fit the model by considering the variable NPS as a binary (Promoters and Non-promoters). Thus, I want to split my data into training and test sets before performing a glm. For the training set to be representative, I'm trying to have 50% promoters and 50% non-promoters in the data set.

My first question: is this a valid approach?

Second question: I tried below code to split the data set and I was able to generate the training set.

```
table(mydata$NPS)
#    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
#   18    31    49    62    90   217   514  2332 10600  6557  2003

nrow(mydata) # = 22473

#total number of promoters = 8560
#total number of non-promoters = 13913

8560*0.8 #=6848 80% of promoters count

#all the promoters 
data_promoters<-mydata[(mydata$NPS==10 | mydata$NPS==9),]
#all the non promoters
data_nonPromoters<-mydata[(mydata$NPS!=10 & mydata$NPS!=9),]

dim(data_promoters) #8560    32
dim(data_nonPromoters) #13913    32

set.seed(100)

sample_promoters <- data_promoters[sample(1:nrow(data_promoters),6848),]
sample_nonPromoters <- data_nonPromoters[sample(1:nrow(data_nonPromoters),6848),]

#train dataset
train_mydata <- rbind(sample_promoters, sample_nonPromoters)
head(train_mydata)
tail(train_mydata)
dim(train_mydata) #13696 32

#test dataset
test_mydata<-mydata[-train_mydata, ]
```

When forming the test set as above, I get the below error. Could you please help me fix this? Thanks a lot!

```
Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Your first question sounds like a statistical analysis issue, better on cross validated (the stats stack exchange site).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `anti_join` from `dplyr` to get rows from `mydata` which are not present in `train_mydata`

```
test_mydata <- dplyr::anti_join(mydata, train_mydata)
```

Comment: When I select a random sample for the train set (code: train_mydata4 <- cr_mydata4.selected[sample(nrow(cr_mydata4.selected), 16855),]) and try to select the test set with the above code, it selects the first set of rows from the original data set, not a random test set. Any reason? (Before selecting the train set, I set the seed to 100) Appreciate your support! :)

Comment: @user13178113 I don't understand what you mean by `it selects the first set of rows from the original data set`. If `cr_mydata4.selected` has all the rows, you select random rows in `train_mydata4`, now to get remaining rows you can do `test_mydata4 <- dplyr::anti_join(cr_mydata4.selected,train_mydata4)`

Comment: I checked the IDs of both train and test sets. head(data.frame(as.integer(rownames(train_mydata4)))) <br/>1  11399
2                               10249
3                               18345
4                                5199
5                               17406
6                               10449 <br/>head(data.frame(as.integer(rownames(test_mydata4)))) <br/> 1                                  1
2                                  2
3                                  3
4                                  4
5                                  5
6                                  6

Comment: Row IDs of the train set are 11399, 10249, 18345, 5199, 17406, 10449, etc. and row IDs of test set are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. Therefore the train set seems random while the latter doesn't look like random.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

`train_mydata` is a `data.frame` and therefore it is a `list`. When subsetting `mydata`, you can only use a vector as index, but here you are using a list, hence the error `invalid subscript type 'list'`.

What I would normally do in this context is to give each row an ID, and then simply do

```
test_mydata <- mydata[!(mydata$ID %in% train_mydata$ID), ]
```